# How to get 'build when a change is pushed to github' option when creating new job

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am trying to create a new job in jenkins which monitors master branch in my github. But while am creating the job, I do not see 'build when a change is pushed to github' option under Build Trigger section. I want automatic build to take place every time a commit is done on my master branch in github.

From all the digging I did, I understand that its called webhook(not completely sure what it does). I tried searching plugins in Jenkins but I didn't find any.
I am new to Jenkins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `GitHub Plugin`.

> Manage Jenkins-->Manage Plugins--Available--> Search for `GitHub Plugin` and install it.

Then you should be able to see the option show in the job config page under `Build Trigger` section.

[image]

As always, I suggest you go to [Git plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) to have a look on how to use it and how to get the webhook works.

There is also a [helpful post](http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github) that you can refer to.

Comment: Good god, I thought I had installed it but what I installed was git plugin. Just got to know git is different from github. Thanks man

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question initially sent me on a wild goose chase of changing settings to no avail. Then I stumbled upon this:

[image]

As it turns out, I had it all along!

Reference: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin